# Selenium - Can't get text from element (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get the result of an input from:
https://web2.0calc.com/

But I can't get the result. I've tried:

```
result = browser.find_element_by_id("input")

result.text

result.get_attribute("textContent")

result.get_attribute("innerHtml")

result.get_attribute("textContent")
```

But it doesn't work and returns an empty string...

Comment: The item on that page with `id="result"` is an image.  Images don't have any of those attributes.

Comment: Seems like a POST request is also made if you can emulate that.

Comment: you right i meant to put id="input" 
which is not an image

Comment: @kobyt, check [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53796300/selenium-cant-get-text-from-element-python/53796435#53796435)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required element is a Base64 image, so you can either get a Base64 value from `@src`, convert it to an image and get a value with a tool like [PIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library) (quite complicated approach) or you can get a result with a direct API call:

```
import requests

url = 'https://web2.0calc.com/calc'
data = data={'in[]': '45*23'}  # Pass your expression as a value

response = requests.post(url, data=data).json()
print(response['results'][0]['out'])
#  1035
```

If you need the value of `#input`:

```
print(browser.find_element_by_id('input').get_attribute('value'))
```

Comment: print(browser.find_element_by_id('input').get_attribute('value'))

works! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My preference would be for the POST example (+ for that) given but you can grab the expression and evaluate that using [`asteval`](http://newville.github.io/asteval/). There may be limitations on `asteval`. It is safer than `eval`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from asteval import Interpreter

d = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://web2.0calc.com/'
d.get(url)
d.maximize_window()
d.find_element_by_css_selector('[name=cookies]').click()
d.find_element_by_id('input').send_keys(5)
d.find_element_by_id('BtnPlus').click()
d.find_element_by_id('input').send_keys(50)
d.find_element_by_id('BtnCalc').click()
expression = ''

while len(expression) == 0:
    expression = d.find_element_by_id('result').get_attribute('title')

aeval = Interpreter()
print(aeval(expression))
d.quit()
```

Comment: Isn't there a risk of a thrown exception from one of the find_element_by_id() or find_element_by_css_selector() calls? Is there automatic synchronisation?